# If $ x > y $ and $a > b$ then is $xa + by \ge xb + ay$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-explanation

Given that $a,b,x,y\ge 0$: I am trying to prove that if $x > y $ and $a > b$ then $xa + by \ge xb + ay$ but I can't seem to prove that this is true

I feel like we need to prove that $xa > xb$ and $by > ay$ but $by$ will never be greater than $ay$. Therefore I am trying to find a counterexample.

Comment: There is no counterexample, unfortunately. The inequality is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Note that $$\begin{align*}
xa+by-xb-ay 
&= x(a-b)-y(a-b) \\
&= (x-y)(a-b)>0\tag{1}
\end{align*}
$$
Since we have $x>y$ and $a>b$. From $(1)$, $$xa+by-xb-ay>0 \iff xa+by>xb+ay$$So we have the result desired.  We are done!

Answer (score 2):

As $x\gt y\gt0$ and $a\gt b\gt0$, we can write $x=y+k$, with $k>0$.

Then the LHS is $(y+k)a+yb = y(a+b) + ka$ and the RHS is $(y+k)b+ya=y(a+b)+kb$

Replacing into the equation, we get $ka>kb$, so the inequality is true.